# xpath return default value ,if value of attribute not found using text()

Tags: xpath, pyspark

```
sample_xml='<employees>\
    <person id="p1">\
        <name value="Alice">ALICE</name>\
    </person>\
    <person id="p2">\
        <name value="Alice">BOB</name>\
    </person>\
    <person id="p3">\
        <name value="Alice"/>\
    </person>\
</employees>'

data = [
  [f'{sample_xml}']  
    ]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['data'])
df=df.selectExpr(
  'xpath(data,"/employees/person/name[@value=\'Alice\']/text()") test'   
  )
```

this gives expcted ["ALICE", "BOB"]

**Problem**:

I want my result to be ["ALICE", "BOB","NA"]

i.e for empty path like below

```
<name value="Alice"/>
```

I want to return a default NA .

is it possible to achieve this ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

With XPath itself this is not possible. It can only return you the actual values of the matching nodes or nothing if no match.
In order to get `NA` or any other data that is not actually contained in the XML, you should wrap the basic XPath request with some additional, external code to return the customized output in case of no match.

Comment: Please could you share some examples of external code in pyspark/python to achieve the desired result

Comment: I'm not familiar with pyspark, I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

In XPath 2.0, use `/employees/person/name[@value=\'Alice\'] /(string(text()), 'NA')[1]"`.

It can't be done in XPath 1.0. In XPath 1.0 there's no such thing as a sequence of strings; you can only return a sequence of nodes, and you can only return nodes that are actually present in the input document.

Comment: df=df.selectExpr(
  'xpath(data,"/employees/person/name[@value=\'Alice\']/(string(text()),\'NA\')[1]")'
  )     Invalid XPath '/employees/person/name[@value='Alice']/(string(text()),'NA')[1]'javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: A location step was expected following the '/' or '//' token

Comment: not able to make this work with Pyspark,could be xpath version issue

Comment: I don't know PySpark but unless you can find evidence to the contrary, it quite possible only supports the old XPath 1.0 standard.